# TypeScript keeping class inside a Map

Tags: typescript, casting

It's too complicated to explain what I need to get, let me show a code with some comments.
I think it will be much clearer.

```js
abstract class Base {
    abstract getType(): string;

    static test(): string[] {
        return [];
    }
}
class Foo extends Base {    
    foo =  '123';

    getType(): string {
        return "foo";
    }

    static test(): string[] {
        return ["a", "b", "c"]
    }
}
class Bar extends Base {    
    bar =  '321';

    getType(): string {
        return "bar";
    }
    static test(): string[] {
        return ["a", "b", "c"]
    }
}

// The following map is a temporary solution just to show what I want to get
// I supposed the map has to have another type instead of "any"
const m = new Map<string, any>();
m.set("foo", Foo);
m.set("bar", Bar);

console.log(m.get('foo').test()); // << I need to have access to static functions and it works with "any" type


function func(it: Base) {
    const baseType = it.getType();

    if (m.has(baseType)) {
        const cl = m.get(baseType);

        const item = it as cl; // << error: 'cl' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof cl'?
        console.log(item);
    }
}

// I know I could do it by the following way, but in this case if I will want to add a few more new classes I will have to update many palces in the code.
// I'd like just to add a new class into the map without updating the entire code.
function func2(it: Foo|Bar) { 
    const baseType = it.getType();
    console.log(baseType, it)
}


const fooInst = new Foo();
func(fooInst);
func2(fooInst);
```

[This code in the playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgg3gFAIkKiQzwIDmOEAKgJ4AOOAFAJQBcCFAlgDtqAbkLFSkYBD6wEEHJE49%20QgNoBdAuNKkodAK5QBCDaJ0BfQpZRoMAMQD2DhDgAe8gQBMM2MHnw62ggAZk4IALwkAOQAjABMAMxRokG0DCzs3LzQgtRaOjp6EIbGAEShDqVmpJZBktKy8opZKtQa%20QUkRSUmpcClADQIpSCDw7Cl6kGW1qjoWMBQLu44Xj64BIE6IIsR0QlxMcliOmlMrErZULkdnd1GwztQVdN1EFIycgoQl63tRJ0ugYHqo%20mMRuCJlMLFYxAB6OEIegACzwoWQyAcAHcbgBbYDMBB8DDAL645gOGBQRi8BzIfTSBzGABW%20kgcmcYGR2IQWORUgQAElecABIgIM40oQEULePpmBS-J45KiEPjCfyMBKEPyAG54UUOCCopYQDJEgSQHDAZUOYLDUWMUqEWBM9m4vYCHBYhAAWQJAB5WkNHQA%20TiiXEAOj8P3KTjGjgcHEjMbobBGizG2CgKbErstdJwUcx1DY0bSbCiFSiHCjTR%20HBTCBlAYDsq9OGV2r1BtgsAUWs57waIX0AngfDdZC8RMQWMpAGsMDjjQ6BE65BkxIRguPJ0yxxO2HwIDxfDgOLckG7EDs-Oc8JFT1GzhkIydSHx7eWo5q2PeOCPk2146AW7IoHsFbpoBwEpICN6Wogp44B6z6IGgSDIMILaIm2LhQFAlI8FEKBRAgejBDgUBDmQCC6sA9I4EMIAMkSGAgDgNxsl2ZAklurA6tRxYIAAInwyqMA4%20hqtaxhRGarB2lhUQAPxBGBbpFiWDhlihuJ5jCtQysKi4CDywquvoyDKp4zinggIA0saaJ0piOJCCKjAsWxggqsSSAbN%20so4hiIpihyZCeMqpJUT6uKUngXo%20jY6AKCFfBhb2kXyp4Uh4PiG4IMwjEDhgfkuTenjFtKiKClEyrIHwi54Ky7LajaMUIMlWG2Ba2qVeqvKntybG5R8nmVas0h6FVNV7hOjLGAtsBxCeZ4IEmAA%20OZXgEQTgXeuCPnsL5vhchmkOB2mlgBx0ZEMp4cLC%20a3iETiCkhnreptTgfitbAVJ9kB5ita1A0heZAA)

What I want to get:

- I want to have a Map or an Object with a list of classes for me to be able to get data from them in a loop (from static functions)
- I have some places in my code where a function gets the Base class as an argument. And I need to cast it to a correct class by `getType()`.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYY5zW) meet your needs?  I strongly recommend making your known subtypes of `Base` form a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) and using only that union type and never `Base` in your code.  You don't want to deal with random possible subtypes of `Base`, right?

Comment: Many thanks! This is exactly what wanted to get!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Map or an Object with a list of classes

In TypeScript, a list of classes can be achieved using a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).

In order for a union to work with static members of a class, you should also use the [`typeof` keyword](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html).

## Casting to a type based on a property

In order to cast to a type based on a property of the base object, you need to use type guards.

### Type guards

A type guard is a check that makes sure that a given argument is of the type. This can either be the `typeof` keyword, i.e. `typeof arg == "string"`, or a user-defined typeguard;

```
function isArgString(arg: any): arg is string => {
    return typeof arg == "string";
}
```

## Recap

To recap, the way to make your map work is using a union, and for your casting, use typeguards:

```
type myUnion = typeof Foo | typeof Bar;


export const isBar = (arg: Base): arg is Bar => {
    return arg.getType() === 'bar';
}


export const isFoo = (arg: Base): arg is Foo => {
    return arg.getType() === 'foo';
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBASygIQIYCc4F44AoMDmAXHGlAKYCUJhiUpG2AfHAN7ACQ65MAruhDiEAdAR4AVAJ4AHcrkrYsOAOQAjDMoDcwAL7B94aPCQAxMGGx5CJMlRroCdOGYtYW7Lj36CRYmFNl5RRUAM3MtXX1gVFVYdFQQeBAAG1Qoels2YDgcoViYeMS4PwC5ajg4hAgCbWzc2FQYBBA4GHJYeRJK6oBtAF0s3KG4bj4BOH7tIb09FLT6FzhyAA82iAATDLTyNiG6nLDXHOUARgAmAGYI-eKJGTKugqrHdmHc0e84ACJDr6ncvQ3BpNFptDrlboEfqDN4jLzjHpfVBfAA031UqO+IC+fRugKGhwAsjwABZgdZBV6wwxQMDJcjCZJgAi4L4uYkwMnrACEX0oeMic3SDEwKzWmwYFF2uRu6kwODgyguZxO1yGJXunQqT2qMLeH3GXzlfwFQ2BzVa7RgWsh0Kp+vhgkRyLRRsxX2xuOm+iGco5XLwCntwxpdIZTJZXzQ6H95N5-O9gJg9zgAFtJABVCAISCWZOyMAhZzmOAAH1a90LItqwAA9LW4OISTswskmQB3Z5p1DSJyoS2p6RgeLoSQVOm8Jq5gBWvFgrQsUDJ7bg7ZJjTgAElV6gIPAYBY-HWG9uoLxpEOKOtWs3u731-QD3B1wA3Ha7sCc8iYfM7KqwchUGvKskQgSQvlASB51TSwIHIFdCR7AAeSE0XTLMcwgJh5G0VNhAoa0fnMTEXEoXD8J4VljTRaMyIMKCw0ZZlcDwvxcGUQ5lEoAB+YQwWtSgyLges4CQpCtzgODyGvJ9X3fEAQHaR9FxgRoLRCXgIESTD6F3a8EHgdthwAa3oTtOW+XdwIrWQog0rSp0EeyQFwAybG2IMbhpeB1AoUpLAM0Q7kCOibgQIsWOEB9cF88hSkEvUQygpJkksVjKNi+LalhRAIqQaNXJgBLgxywK-VJckcJub1qtycK8FMcxCuK2q3kCokKopOicr0RN9BE7djIgMAV23cBeGSa91gsAy4FUMcvzgVsOy7dtUEkNFVEnRBBE5JA4BAbZcokzs2x3PcFyEdZr37EJ4LTYcdjglchQoeht1O1K5Mu891kaHZUysuBpFQZJFPoKobx2cB1gZY8t2Ua9kgQYydlnecnyAm7JPu16dqfRbAd7cyyW2361N1RbyD3BBuAO8k4ecxyls0kAzkKkgXFLWjdi85K5u2fycECjUQv+HJQ3pJiWUy+40QM-lAUgowlvMTcVZwZ7izAKrvIF9B1fnTX7oKujnNwQ5DaK7RnPZy2jDN1mYowK3Ha09m5Vd7QgA)